# Variable 'data' might have not been defined

Tags: php, for-loop, phpstorm

I'm working on a function that displays data but I keep getting warning "*Variable 'data' might have not been defined*"

```
  function getAllData() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM patient, person WHERE patient.Patient = person.Personnummer ";
        if(!$sql = mysql_query($query)) {
            throw new exception("Error: CAn not execute the query.");
        } else {
            $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if($num>0)
            {
                for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
                {
                    $data[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;  //<--Variable 'data' might have not been defined
    }
```

Comment: If your SQL query yields an empty result, it *will* be undefined. Also, please stop using `mysql_` functions and switch to either mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is your IDE that is giving you that warning, not php when you execute your script (it might, but the warning would be different).

To avoid it, make sure it is always defined:

```
function getAllData() {
    $data = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM patient, person WHERE patient.Patient = person.Personnummer ";
    ...
```

Now an empty array will be returned from your function if for example no rows are found. In your current code, php would generate a warning at run-time about an undefined variable when you run your script and no rows are found.